# Where is Netbeans Java Web Project Template?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have Netbeans 8.2 with Java JDK 1.8 installed. When I create a new project, Java Web is not listed. Is there something else I need to install?

Ultimately, I want to create a Spring app but you have to go through the Java Web template to reach Spring.

Comment: You need to download the Java EE version of Netbeans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tools menu
2. Select Plugins
3. Click on the "Available Plugins" tab
4. Sort the list by name
5. Check the box for "Java Web and EE"
6. Click install
7. Click your way through the dialogs
8. Restart Netbeans